# MeteorJS - Promise.await blocking

Tags: meteor

In a Meteor method running on server only I wrap a promise as follow:

```
'my.method'(){
    const instance = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost'});
    return Promise.await(instance.post('/endpoint', data));

}
```

It works, but it's a long request (takes a couple of minutes to get the result), and while the request is pending, the app is blocked: I can still click on links and change the route and display other (React) components, but all data flows are interrupted until the request has returned.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to use this.unblock() inside your meteor method. You can find an in depth explanation [here.](https://medium.com/@pmuens/meteor-defer-and-this-unblock-e610c8426065)

```
'my.method'(){
    this.unblock();
    const instance = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost'});
    Promise.await(instance.post('/endpoint', data));
}
```